# Azure APIM Integration with Duende (Identity Server) as an inbound policy on an API operation

Tags: azure-api-management, duende-identity-server

I've searched extensively but found no support on the above subject "Azure APIM Integration with Duende (Identity Server) as an inbound policy on an API operation"

Here's what we are trying to accomplish.

1. For now, we are successfully getting a token from Duende with a client id and client secret
2. Using postman as a mocking UI client and adding the Bearer token and posting to an APIM API to Duende to get authorization to designated backend microservices
3. We want to add a policy inbound fragment as a way of authorizing backend resources
4. Based on response from Duende we can redirect in the policy code

Has anyone coded this in Identity Server 4 or Duende?

We have tried a simple GET to Duende using the following policy on an inbound operation. Since the token now contains the client_id we assume no need to send it again to authorize?

```xml
 <set-variable name="token" value="eyJhbGciOiJS......." />
    <!-- Send request to Token Server to validate token (see RFC 7662) -->
    <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="tokenstate" timeout="20" ignore-error="false">
        <set-url>http://myidentityserver/connect/authorize</set-url>
        <set-method>GET</set-method>
        <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
            <value>@($"Bearer {(string)context.Variables["token"]}")</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</value>
        </set-header>
    </send-request>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually how we do it is we obtain token from identity server and validate it in APIM using JWT policy in this case you are making a call to identity server (Duende) from APIM but nowhere authorizing it. To pre-Authorize requests, we can use  Policy by validating the access tokens of each incoming request. If a request does not have a valid token, API Management blocks it please refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT